# change parent -> childs to childs javascript

Tags: javascript

Have a code with One Parent and 8 childs, I want childs class "b" to be in childs class "a".
Have a code with parentElement class and 8 childs, I want childs class "secondElement" to be in childs class "firstElement".
Have JS code that can fix it, but there isa bug because elements get appended to each other in random way.
The code:

```
<div class="parentElement">

<a class="firstElement">
</a>
<div class="secondElement">
</div>

<a class="firstElement">
</a>
<div class="secondElement">
</div>

<a class="firstElement">
</a>
<div class="secondElement">
</div>

<a class="firstElement">
</a>
<div class="secondElement">
</div>

</div>
```

> After JS work:

```
<div class="parentElement">

<a class="firstElement">
   <div class="secondElement">
   </div>
</a>

<a class="firstElement">
   <div class="secondElement">
   </div>
</a>

<a class="firstElement">
   <div class="secondElement">
   </div>
</a>

<a class="firstElement">
   <div class="secondElement">
   </div>
</a>

</div>
```

> Here is snippet with my code implementation.

```js
function getElement() {
        var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('parentElement')
        for(var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++)  
      var parentLength = parent[i];

   var firstElements =  parentLength.getElementsByClassName('firstElement'),
             firstElementsLength = firstElements.length,
    secondElements =  parentLength.getElementsByClassName('secondElement');
         
         while(firstElementsLength--) {
             var secondElementsLength = secondElements.length;
             while(secondElementsLength--) {
  firstElements[firstElementsLength].appendChild(secondElements[secondElementsLength]);
             }
         }
 }

 getElement();
```

```html
<div class="parentElement">

    <a class="firstElement">
      firstElement1
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
      secondElement2
    </div>

    <a class="firstElement">
      firstElement1
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
      secondElement2
    </div>
      
    <a class="firstElement">
      firstElement1
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
      secondElement2
    </div>

    <a class="firstElement">
      firstElement1
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
      secondElement2
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble understanding your question. Could you go over the english and fix the html codes as well? There are 3 different ones.

Comment: You realize your class is parent not parentElement right? Your html says parent but your JavaScript says parentElement. Why do you have two sets of html code? Please delete one for clarity as they appear to be duplicate.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse I changed both the code and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably an easier way to look at this, but here are a few changes that could add the divs to your anchor tags.

```js
function getElement() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parentElement"), 
    firstElements = parent.getElementsByClassName('firstElement'),
 secondElements =  parent.getElementsByClassName('secondElement'),
 elementsLength = firstElements.length;

  while(elementsLength--) {
    firstElements[elementsLength].appendChild(secondElements[elementsLength]);
  }
    
  output.value = parent.innerHTML;
}

getElement();
```

```css
textarea {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
    <a class="firstElement">
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
    </div>

    <a class="firstElement">
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
    </div>
      
    <a class="firstElement">
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
    </div>

    <a class="firstElement">
    </a>
    <div class="secondElement">
    </div>

    <textarea id="output"></textarea>
</div>
```

Assuming that you have the same number of elements with the `firstElement` and `secondElement` class, this will get an array of all of the tags with the `firstElement` class, an array with the `secondElement` class, and the length of how many there are. Then we loop through each of them(again, assuming we have the same number of each **and** they're formatted this way, one after the other) and add the `div` to the `anchor`.

Another note. Since there's only 1 parent element here, you can use an `id` instead of a `class` for it. That way we can get the element by id instead of an array of elements by class name.

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjmnq7an/1/) that I was looking at for modification. Note that the `textarea` is only there to show the HTML after the function is called.

Comment: Yeah!This is it! Thank u very much for your help!!

Comment: @Vladyslav, glad I could help :)